# how to give access to a certain page of website by checking with database without providing the field for user to specify to which course he belongs

Tags: php

I want to allow a user belonging to certain field data(coure="PGDCA")        in database to login the specific page.

I'am stuck at checking whether the student belongs to that certain field data.

```php
else {
    if($this->input->post('login')) {

        $u=$this->input->post('username');
        $p=$this->input->post('password');
    }

    // call method of Login_Model and pass variables as parameter
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
    $result['output']=$this->Login_model->check_course();
    if($this->Login_model->check($u,$p)) {

        $session_data=array('username'=> $u);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        echo Modules::run('stu_hm/index',$session_data,$result);
        // $this->load->view('output',$result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can't see any check for `course == 'PGDCA'`.

Comment: i dont know how to check whether the user belongs to that particular course by getting the field from database

Comment: What is contained in `$result['output']`? I'm sorry but I don't really get your code. How is your `Login_model` is looking like, i.e. which fields does it contain?

Comment: $result['output'] contains data fetched from the table. i'am using codeigniter framework. Login_model  contains functions named 'check' which checks the database for username and password and function 'check_course' to select all data from the table and it return that query as result() which is then stored in $result['output'].

Comment: thanks,i got the answer to my q i didnt got the logic at first

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Otherwise, post a `var_dump` or `print_r` of your `$result['output']` please.

Comment: thank you for your replies,i actually didn't wrote the code for checking specific user(like two different course which the user have applied for).Following is the code that i have used to check for a specific user :
if($this->Login_model->check_pgdca($u,$p)){
$session_data=array('username'=> $u);
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
echo Modules::run('stu_hm/index');